# How to replace underscores with spaces and apply title casing to column name strings with preg_replace_callback()?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback, title-case

I can't seem to get the `preg_replace()` to change to `preg_replace_callback()`.

In an attempt to make database table columns more human-friendly when I display them, I am trying to replace underscores with spaces and make every word start with a capital letter.

```
function tidyUpColumnName($_colName) {

    // Check for blank and quit
    if(empty($_colName)) return false;

    // Replace underscore and next lowercase letter with space uppercase and Capitalise first letter
    $newColName = ucfirst(preg_replace_callback('/_[a-z]/uis', '" ".substr(strtoupper("$0"), 1)', $_colName));
    return $newColName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a function in a replacement value with `preg_replace()` anymore.  This is why `preg_replace_callback()` is used.

`preg_replace_callback()` expects a function in the second parameter.

```
preg_replace_callback('/_([a-z])/ui', function($m) { return " " . strtoupper($m[1]); }, $_colName)
```

You don't need the `s` pattern modifier because you aren't using any `.` characters in your pattern.

You can avoid `substr()` if you use a capture group and nominate `$m[1]` in your replacement function.

---

**Hmm, if I understand your intent, you don't need regex at all...**

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Uv7ZT))

```
$string = "what_the_hey_now";    
// echo ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $string));  // not multibyte safe
echo mb_convert_case(str_replace("_", " ", $string), MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

Output:

```
What The Hey Now
```